# Linux kernel print_hex_dump_bytes

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I use print_hex_dump_bytes function as following in Linux kernel:

```
    print_hex_dump_bytes("digest: ", DUMP_PREFIX_ADDRESS, digest, 32);
```

The output is as follows, what does the part inside the red box mean?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right box shows the ASCII representation of your hexadecimal dump (only showing printable characters). This is especially useful for printing strings.

For instance, the 2nd char of your dump is `0x39` which is rightfully displayed as a 9 (cf. ASCII table)

A similar behavior can be found in the command `xxd`.